# How to loop through all OWL entities and get all its nested elements?

Tags: java, owl, owl-api

I have owl file that I need to parse using Java. I am using Java OWL API. I read the file and I was able to return all classes and properties.

```
 OWLOntologyManager manager=OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
 OWLOntology owl=manager.loadOntologyFromOntologyDocument(new File(myOWLFile));
 System.out.println(owl.getAxiomCount());
 java.util.Set<OWLEntity> entOnt = owl.getSignature();
 for (OWLEntity a : entOnt) {
    System.out.println("Entity "+a);//this print only the entities
}
```

However, I need to trace all nested elements inside each entity. For example, if this is the owl file:

```
<owl:Class rdf:about="#A">
        <owl:equivalentClass rdf:resource="#B"/>
        <rdfs:subClassOf rdf:resource="#C"/>
    </owl:Class>

  <owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="#D">
        <rdfs:range rdf:resource="#E"/>
        <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="#F"/>
    </owl:ObjectProperty>
```

I need to get all elements inside the A class. I need to now that A contains B as equivalentClass and C as subClass. I need to print something like this:

```
Class: A has
      B = Equivalent Class
      C = Sub Class
Property: D has
      E = Range
      F = Domain
```

How to loop through all owl entities and get all its nested elements?

Comment: "inside the A class" doesn't make sense. Entities in OWL are classes, properties and individuals. What you are talking about are owl **axioms** - you want to get simply all OWL axioms for a given class - that is your target. You can use http://owlcs.github.io/owlapi/apidocs_5/org/semanticweb/owlapi/search/EntitySearcher.html - the other option would be to iterate all axioms, handle each axiom type separately

Answer (score 1):

The nested elements are just the XML structured representation of OWL axioms (the mapping between OWL axioms and RDF triples, of which the XML snippet is the RDF/XML representation, is available on the [W3C web site](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-mapping-to-rdf/) ).

To access the axioms and group them in a for similar to your intended output, you'd be doing something similar to what OWLAPI does when saving an ontology: for each entity, retrieve the axioms where that entity is on the left hand side (e.g., `A subclassOf B` is an axiom where A is on the left hand side) and visit the axiom accordingly.

OWLAPI defines an `OWLAxiomVisitor` interface, which you can implement for the axiom types you're interested in, for example:

```
    owl.getClassesInSignature().forEach(c->{
        Printer p=new Printer(c);
        owl.getReferencingAxioms(c).forEach(axiom->axiom.accept(p));
    });
```

Printer class:

```
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.*;

public class Printer implements OWLAxiomVisitor {
    private OWLClassExpression e;
    public Printer(OWLClassExpression e) {
        this.e = e;
    }
    @Override
    public void visit(OWLSubClassOfAxiom axiom) {
      if (e.equals(axiom.getSubClass())) {
        System.out.println(axiom.getSubClass() + " subClassOf" + axiom.getSuperClass());
      } else {
        System.out.println(axiom.getSubClass() + " superClassOf" + axiom.getSuperClass());
      }
    }
    @Override
    public void visit(OWLEquivalentClassesAxiom axiom) {
      System.out.println(e + " equivalent to " + axiom.getClassExpressionsMinus(e));
    }
...
}
```